# VTK - 2D Point cloud within an ellipse

Tags: c++, vtk

Using VTK, I want to create a cloud of points (random amount)  located inside an ellipse.

So far I've got this:

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPointSource> pointSource = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPointSource>::New();
pointSource->SetCenter(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
pointSource->SetNumberOfPoints(nPoints);
pointSource->SetRadius(radius);
pointSource->Update();
```

However I wonder how to describe it as an *elliptical shaped cloud*.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a vtkTransform to convert the point source sphere to an ellipse. Here's an example that scales a plane: http://www.vtk.org/gitweb?p=VTK.git;a=blob;f=Examples/Modelling/Python/expCos.py